# My web page only prints onto 1 page (there is no break)

Tags: javascript, html, printing, break

I'm having trouble printing a web page of information, which should span onto about 3 pages. Currently, only 1 page is printed, and the rest of the data is not visible anywhere? Is there some JS or HTML I can use to break the page, and allow the information to continue being printed on the next pages.

Comment: Who's voting to close this?  Why? It's a perfectly good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a print stylesheet, and it should have height set to "auto" and overflow set to "visible" for the body. What I do is something like:

```
@media print {
    html, body { height: auto; overflow: visible; }
}
```

Just put that in your main CSS file or in a file of its own.

Comment: Yes I already have these properties set in a print stylesheet :S

Comment: Well try adding "! important" after "visible" and before the semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

There's a pretty good article on A List Apart about preparing your site for print.

There is a known bug with floated divs getting cut off, it might be worthwhile for you to take a look.

[A List Apart / CSS Design: Going to Print](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) (See the section: Fixing a float flub)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can also force your breaks

```
<style>
.break { page-break-before: always; }
</style>
<body>
content on page 1...
<h1 class="break">text of Heading 1 on page 2</h1>
content on page 2...
<h1 class="break">text of Heading 1 on page 3</h1>
content on page 3...
<p class="break">content on top of page 4</p>
content on page 4...
</body>
```